# Node Red - Send Device to Gateway Publish/Subscribe - IBM Bluemix simulator

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, node-red, watson-iot

My requirement is to create Node red app to read a message from n devices and m gateways and publish to IBM IOT as MQTT using MQTT node, also process and store it in cloudant DB. If there any update then the device should subscribe for the commands. 
I read from IBM blue mix portal and was able to send and receive the message for gateways using MQTT node to IBM IOT node.

Need clarification on the below,

1. can use node red simulator to send message from device/gateway
   simultaneously (because gateway will send the message directly to IBM Watson IOT but devices always will send a message to gateway)
2. How to identify or differentiate the message received from device
   /Gateway in Watson IOT node
3. How the sequence of the message published? is in FIFO order?
4. Time to live for the message? If MQTT broker disconnected then how
   the message will be published like i.e how many messages can be
       queued and size of the queue?
5. How can we notify MQTT /device disconnected to the other end

Answer (score 0):

Each message published to the Watson IoT platform has a unique client ID to  differentiate the origin of the publisher.

IoT uses a Pub/Sub architecture so messages are published to topics and received by the subscribers.     It is not a point-to-point queue architecture.

Message are saved internally by the Watson IoT platform and you have the option of configuring cloudant DB as historian data storage for your messages as described in this [tutorial.](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloudant-nosql-db-as-historian-data-storage-for-ibm-watson-iot-parti/)